# Electron open dialog hangs when using promise without async/await

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, electron

I'm experiencing very strange error with electron open dialog window. Whenever I open it, it hangs and application becomes frozen.

The logic is straightforward, I have a helper for creating async actions with `typescript-fsa` library. The purpose of it is to call a promise and when it's finished call done/failed actions. It's not the issue with this helper because it works for other 100 epics in the application but it probably does something that conflicts with electron dialog.

```
export function makeAsyncEpic<T, P, S>(
  actionCreator: AsyncActionCreators<T, P, S>,
  asyncMethod: (params: T, state: ApplicationState, action$) => Promise<P>,
  filter?: (action$: Observable<Action>, state: ApplicationState) => boolean,
) {
  return makeObservableEpic(actionCreator, (p, s, a) => Observable.fromPromise(asyncMethod(p, s, a)), filter);
}

export function makeObservableEpic<T, P, S>(
  { started, done, failed }: AsyncActionCreators<T, P, S>,
  observable: (params: T, state: ApplicationState, action$) => Observable<P>,
  filter?: (action$: Observable<Action>, state: ApplicationState) => boolean,
) {
  return (action$: Observable<Action>, store: { getState: () => ApplicationState }) =>
    action$
      .filter(started.match)
      .filter(() => (filter === undefined ? true : filter(action$, store.getState())))
      .switchMap(action =>
        observable(action.payload, store.getState(), action$)
          .map(result => {
            return done({
              params: action.payload,
              result,
            });
          })
          .catch(error => {
            return Observable.of(
              failed({
                params: action.payload,
                error,
              }),
            );
          }),
      );
}
```

The following epic freezes the application when I call actions.openRepository.started:

```
const remote = electron.remote;
const mainProcess = remote.require("./dialog");

export const openDirectoryEpic = makeAsyncEpic(actions.openRepository, mainProcess.openDirectory);
```

The surprising thing is that if I change it to

```
export const openDirectoryEpic = makeAsyncEpic(actions.openRepository, async () => {
  const directory = await mainProcess.openDirectory();
  return directory;
});
```

It works fine. Isn't it equivalent? What is the possible cause?

EDIT:

I can even remove async/await here and put it like this and it works:

```
export const openDirectoryEpic1 = makeAsyncEpic(actions.openRepository, () => mainProcess.openDirectory());
```

Isnt  `() => mainProcess.openDirectory()` equivalent to `mainProcess.openDirectory`?

EDIT2: openDirectory is implemented in this way:

```
import { dialog, ipcMain } from "electron";
import { mainWindow } from "./main";

export const openDirectory = (): Promise<{ directory: string }> =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("Opening dialog");

    const property: "openDirectory" = "openDirectory";
    const options = {
      title: "Select Repository",
      properties: [property],
    };
    try {
      dialog.showOpenDialog(mainWindow, options, (files: string[]) => {
        if (files && files.length === 1) {
          resolve({ directory: files[0] });
        } else {
          reject(`Error when opening directory: ${files}`);
        }
      });
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
  });
```

Comment: I guess that in your first (freezing) solution you are not passing a `Promise`, but some kind of value. Try passing `mainProcess.openDirectory()` instead of `mainProcess.openDirectory`. You did it in your working example, don't know why you didn't in the freezing one :)

Comment: mainProcess.openDirectory is equivalent to () => mainProcess.openDirectory()

Comment: No, it's not. How could it even be equivalent? You even stated in a different comment, that `openDirectory()` returns a promise. How `openDirectory` could return one? It's a property. You can't have a `function` and a `Promise` in the same field.

Comment: in React you can do e.g this: function abc(){} and then bind either with lambda like this: onClick={this.abc} or onClick = {()=>this.abc()} which is equivalent except "this".

Comment: Ok, now i got it, you're right. But I see another difference in your solutions. When you're passing `mainProcess.openDirectory`, your `makeAsyncEpic` function does invoke `openDirectory()` with `(p, s, a)` arguments. When you're passing `() => mainProcess.openDirectory()` the arguments are ignored in the `makeAsyncEpic` invocation.

Comment: @sarneeh yea but openDirectory doesn't have any arguments so they are ignored

Comment: Okay, then I'm out of ideas :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `makeAsyncEpic(actions.openRepository, mainProcess.openDirectory);` you implicitly pass all of the arguments to the openDirectory function and `electron.remote` needs to pack/wrap every argument before it can be sent to the main processor.
In your case, the last argument is an `Observable` type and Electron can have problems with packing it.

Using `makeAsyncEpic(actions.openRepository, () => mainProcess.openDirectory())` you don't pass any arguments to the `openDirectory` function so Electron doesn't have any problems.

I'm guessing that the following syntax `(p, s, a) => mainProcess.openDirectory(p, s, a)` will cause the same problems as the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Where is `openDirectory()`?

[The docs state](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowopendialogbrowserwindow-options-callback) that `showOpenDialog` is synchronous unless you pass a callback.

If you want to call `showOpenDialog` and have it return a promise, you'll have to wrap it correctly. This is what we do from the renderer and it doesn't hang:

```
const { remote } = require('electron');

public selectDirectory(mainWindow: BrowserWindow, defaultPath: string): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
    remote.dialog.showOpenDialog(mainWindow, {
      properties: ['openDirectory'],
      defaultPath: defaultPath
    }, names => {
      resolve(names ? names[0] : undefined);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: You are right. See edit2. I didn't realize it's actually our wrapper. The question however is still unanswered. If you look into the first edit you'll see that it actually comes down to difference between func and () => func() here. Any other function than openDirectory works fine without parathensis

Comment: where is `openDirectory()`? Shouldn't you be trying to call [`dialog.showOpenDialog`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowopendialogbrowserwindow-options-callback)?

Comment: Why are you exporting a const `openDirectory` rather than just exporting function?

Comment: It doesn't really make a difference, does it?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `remote`, you may need to note one important thing: *you are asking synchronous operation*.

https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/remote.md#remote-objects

> When you invoke methods of a remote object, call a remote function, or create a new object with the remote constructor (function), you are actually sending synchronous inter-process messages.

If you'd like to have async behavior, instead of using `remote` setup async ipc channel between process and let main process behaves for async ipc request.

Comment: okay I understand. But still openDirectory() function returns a promise which I can await.

Comment: it can be confusing, but you may actually run profiler to see which part is blocking when you do remote vs. async ipc. call may returns promise, but call itself can still blocking in nature of remote ipc.

Comment: you are right, see edit2. I didn't realize that openDirectory is actually our wrapper